# sql datetime formats conversion

Tags: sql, datetime

How can i convert a datetime of type dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in sql?
I dont want to convert to varchar but to datetime. 
Can anyone give me an idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DateTime` is a `DateTime` is a `DateTime`  - it doesn't have " a format" - it's just a `DateTime`.

The format or display options only come into play when you want to display the `DateTime` as a string.

> of type dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

To me, this sounds as if:

- you have **string** representing a date, in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`
- you want to convert that to a `DateTime` and then again display a string representing that `DateTime` in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Right??

Check out the [MSDN SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)  for CAST and CONVERT - it lists all possible, valid, supported string formats representing a date and time.

Format `dd-mm-yyyy` is style no. 105, so this will convert your first string:

```
SET @YourDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '23-11-2010', 105)
```

Now you have your `DATETIME` value (Nov 23, 2010) in `@YourDateTime` - just a `DateTime`, no formatting applied.

If you want to display that date value in format `dd/mm/yyyy`, which is style no. 103, use this snippet of T-SQL to achieve this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @YourDateTime, 103)
```

This will display `23/11/2010`.